# Service Unavailable on web channel

Tags: .net, botframework

Not sure why now. I am getting error/status 503 Service Unavailable from webchat.botframework.com/api/tokens...
I tried to see my bot configurations (Web channel) loging into https://dev.botframework.com/bots/channels?id=MyBotId&channelId=webchat and this page errors out (YSOD). Wondering anybody else facing this now? Or is it just me. It started happening from today morning.

[image]

Comment: No problem on my side for one of my bots

Comment: @NicolasR A web channel one? I just tried another deployed through a colleague's account and is having the same issue there. Mine: https://bot.rmesi.co.in/Asha.html
It works sometimes looking at network/console(of the browser) gives the details

Comment: Yes, used the URL you provided but just replacing `MyBotId` by my real bot ID. And the bot in the URL of your last comment is replying on my side

Comment: Oh is it can you proceed a bit on that window please. I think the issue is intermittent and depeneds on the region. Because its behaving better when I tried from a VM located in the UK. But still getting the issue. Its intermittent. You should get a 502 or 503 as you go along

Comment: From the UK vm it seems to have sorted. but still no difference from India

Comment: From the chat window I processed a lot of actions, no specific problem. I'm located in France. There's been an outage yesterday around cognitive services / bot framework, maybe you are still having some issues after that

Comment: @NicolasR thanks a lot for checking/helping out. Hope this resolves by itself soon

Comment: Hope for you too. And sorry for the rubbish posted in your dialog value :D

Comment: There is a Direct Line service interruption in North Europe and South East Asia regions.  We're working to get it back online now.

Comment: This incident has been resolved. If you have further issues, please report it on [Microsoft/BotBuilder](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder/issues/new) GitHub repository.